# Where to find and share Python geoprocessing scripts?

Tags: arcpy, open-source-gis

Where are folks storing *and* sharing their Python geoprocessing scripts?  For example, I know that [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=arcpy&ref=cmdform) has some shared scripts.  ESRI is phasing-out [ArcScripts](http://arcscripts.esri.com/), which is still really handy, and directing people to the [Geoprocessing Model and Script Tool Gallery](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing).  What other repositories are available for sharing geoprocessing scripts?